# How Django methods are invokes?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I’m beginner in Django. And I don’t understand how build-in methods Django are invoked.
Let’s say we have this view:

```
class HomeNews(MyMixin, ListView):
    model = News
    template_name = 'news/home_news_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'news'
    paginate_by = 2

    def get_queryset(self):
        return News.objects.filter(is_published=True).select_related('category')

    def my_method1(self, id):
        value = id + 123
        return = value
```

Will how these methods invoked in my app? I don't call these explicitly. Will these invoked automatically?

For example not django code I will invoke like a.method() but here we don't invoke but these work anyway. Explain please, I didn't find any information about this.

Comment: `get_queryset` is used in `GenericViews`, and there are other methods that you can write that are "automatically" invoked. you can see those in the django documentation.

Comment: You can see that you are inheriting the ListView generic View. It is a class already written by other developers. It has a get_queryset method that it calls inside its code which you are overriding.

Comment: @RafaelBarros I've seen it used in this class, but where is it called from? In generic class it is defined but not called as get_queryset().

Comment: I don't know the rest of the code, this isn't a reproducible example. This question is better fit for a different forum.

Comment: Check the get method of BaseListView, Django's generic view involve lots of inheritance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Will how these methods invoked in my app? I don't call these explicitly.

Because the `ListView` has an implementation for `get` that will eventually call `get_queryset`. Indeed, the [**`ListView`** is implemented as [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.2.x/django/views/generic/list.py#L194-L198):

> ```
> class ListView(MultipleObjectTemplateResponseMixin, BaseListView):
>      "…"
> ```

and in the `BaseListView` defines a method [`.get(…)` [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.2.x/django/views/generic/list.py#L141-L158):

> ```
> class BaseListView(MultipleObjectMixin, View):
>     """A base view for displaying a list of objects."""
>     def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
>         self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
>         allow_empty = self.get_allow_empty()
>
>         if not allow_empty:
>             # When pagination is enabled and object_list is a queryset,
>             # it's better to do a cheap query than to load the unpaginated
>             # queryset in memory.
>             if self.get_paginate_by(self.object_list) is not None and hasattr(self.object_list, 'exists'):
>                 is_empty = not self.object_list.exists()
>             else:
>                 is_empty = not self.object_list
>             if is_empty:
>                 raise Http404(_('Empty list and “%(class_name)s.allow_empty” is False.') % {
>                     'class_name': self.__class__.__name__,
>                 })
>         context = self.get_context_data()
>         return self.render_to_response(context)
> ```

The `.get(…)` method thus will call the `.get_queryset(…)` method for which there is an override in your class, then it will check if an empty queryset is allowed, paginate the queryset if necessary, etc., and eventually call the `.render_to_response(…)` method with the context it generated to return a HTTP response.

The `.get(…)` method is not triggered directly. You normally pass `.as_view(…)` in the URL patterns, so that means that the result of `.as_view(…)` is a function as well that will do dispatching and call the `.get(…)` method if it is a GET request, this is implemented in the [**`View`** class [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.2.x/django/views/generic/base.py#L48-L80):

> ```
>     @classonlymethod
>     def as_view(cls, **initkwargs):
>         """Main entry point for a request-response process."""
>         for key in initkwargs:
>             if key in cls.http_method_names:
>                 raise TypeError(
>                     'The method name %s is not accepted as a keyword argument '
>                     'to %s().' % (key, cls.__name__)
>                 )
>             if not hasattr(cls, key):
>                 raise TypeError("%s() received an invalid keyword %r. as_view "
>                                 "only accepts arguments that are already "
>                                 "attributes of the class." % (cls.__name__, key))
>
>         def view(request, *args, **kwargs):
>             self = cls(**initkwargs)
>             self.setup(request, *args, **kwargs)
>             if not hasattr(self, 'request'):
>                 raise AttributeError(
>                     "%s instance has no 'request' attribute. Did you override "
>                     "setup() and forget to call super()?" % cls.__name__
>                 )
>             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
>         view.view_class = cls
>         view.view_initkwargs = initkwargs
>
>         # take name and docstring from class
>         update_wrapper(view, cls, updated=())
>
>         # and possible attributes set by decorators
>         # like csrf_exempt from dispatch
>         update_wrapper(view, cls.dispatch, assigned=())
>         return view
> ```

The `.dispatch(…)` method will thus look what the HTTP method of the request is, and call `.get(…)` in case of a GET request, `.post(…)` in case of a POST request, etc. and will call `.http_method_not_allowed(…)` in case there is no `post`/`get`/… method defined.

Comment: Now i get it, thanks for the detailed answer.
Now I realized that the built-in methods are called for me by the django developers somewhere inside framework.

Comment: @shevdenvla: there is a website that for the class-based views shows how the class is implemented and thus shows the implementations of the inherited classes: https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.0/django.views.generic.list/ListView/ this is often useful, although it requires some "skill" to be able to "read" it effectively, so often after a while it can help understand how these views work,.

Comment: tell me please, it does exist something like this for django rest-framework views?